# Solve $\frac{dy}{dt} = y$ with inital condition y(0) = -1, t(0) = 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $\frac{dy}{dt} = y$ with inital condition y(0) = -1, t(0) = 0

attempt
$\int \frac{dy}{y} = \int dt$

$lny = t + c$

$lny = t + lnc$
$y = ce^t$
$y(0) = -1 = c$

so $y = t =1$

Comment: Soooooooooooooo.... wheres the question/

Comment: Actually, since $c=-1$, it follows that $y=ce^t=-e^t$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I think many users take "Solve ..." as the question, though it has no actual question marks ;)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt fair enough. I just avoid helping until the OP actually expresses what their question is. The error in the work is clear, but I wanted the *OP to realize this*

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what $t(0)=0$ means, but except that the answer would be 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\ =\ y$$
$$\int\frac{dy}y\ =\ \int dt$$
$$\ln|y|\ =\ t+C$$
$$|y|\ =\ e^{t+c}$$
Since $\ y(0)=-1$, 
$$|y(0)|=|-1|=e^C$$
$$C=0$$
Thus,
$$y=-e^t$$